# Illustrator: Pathfinder tool not letting me erase?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, pathfinder

On my first pattern I was able to trim the edges by selecting everything and then pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> while holding alt but now it's not letting me. Everything is unlocked and ungrouped.

What's going on here?

[image: [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUWvP.png)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your layers panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is for the *Shapebuilder Tool*, not Pathfinder.

The easiest (and best) method to clip those edges is with a *Clipping Mask*

With a clipping mask, it is non-destructive, meaning you can come back and make changes later on.

Simply, create a shape over the area you want to **keep** (that rectangle works) and then select all and **Right Click → Make Clipping Mask** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>)

Note, your clipping path needs to be the shape above everything else as it will pick the topmost shape as the clipping path.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That is so much more effective.

Comment: @C.Mundell glad to be of assistance. Welcome to the site!